# Uniform continuity of a $C^1$ function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ bounded away from a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $\mathbb{S}$ be a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $d(x, \mathbb{S})$ be a distance function defined as

$
   d(x, \mathbb{S}) = \inf\{\|x-y\|: y \in \mathbb{S} \},
$

where $\|x\|$ is the Euclidean norm. Suppose $x: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuously differentiable function that is bounded in a sense that

$
\exists M > 0 \textrm{ such that } d(x(t), \mathbb{S}) \leq M \;\; \forall t \geq 0.
$

Then, is it possible to prove that $x(t)$ is uniformly continuous on the set
$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: d(x, \mathbb{S}) < M\}$, or to provide a counter example? I think this is non-trivial since the set is non-compact, but the properties of linearity of the subspace would be helpful to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The counter-example exists already in dimension 1. Think of $\Bbb{R}$, $S=\{0\}$ and $x(t)=sin(t^2)$.

Comment: You're right. the slope of $\sin t^2$ is unbounded so cannot be uniformly continuous. Thanks.